# How to implement persistent lookup table

Tags: java, memory-management, persistence

My Java application uses a read-only lookup table, which is stored in an XML file. When the application starts it just reads the file into a `HashMap`. So far, so good, but since the table is growing I don't like loading the *entire* table into the memory at once. RDBMS and NoSQL key-value stores seem overkill to me. What would you suggest?

Comment: how large is the table / how big might it get? depending on the answer to that you may find that loading it all into memory is still the best option....

Answer (score 1):

Makes you wish Java would allow to allocate infinite amounts of heap as memory mapped file :-)

If you use Java 5, then use Java DB; it's a database engine written in Java, based on [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/). If you know SQL, then setting up an embedded database takes only a couple of minutes. Since you can create the database again every time your app is started, you don't have to worry about permissions, DB schema migration, stale caches, etc.

Or you could use an OO database like [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/) but many people find it hard to make the mental transition to use queries to iterate over internal data structures. To take your example: You have a huge `HashMap`. Instead of using `map.get()`, you have to build a query using DB4o and then run that query on your map to locate items; otherwise DB4o would be forced to load the whole map at once.

Another alternative is to create your own minimal system: Read the data from the XML file and save it as a large random access file plus an index + caching so you can quickly look up items. If your objects are all serializable, then you can use `ObjectInputStream` to read the individual entries after seeking to the right place using the `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: It is interesting if there is an open source implementation of the last alternative you mentioned. I guess this pattern -- random access file + index + cache -- should be part of any data base (e.g. Derby).

Comment: It is but even OSS DBs think that this is private so you can't reuse the code.